# In dependency walker, Is there a way to get a simple list of unresolved dependancies?

Tags: windows, dll, java-native-interface

I'm making a jni call to a huge windows dll that I have source to and have built, and when I call loadlibrary it fails with "Can't find dependent libraries". Seeing as I have built it I assume everything I need is on the machine somewhere...
I'm going through dependency walker and I find the usual "WNetRestoreConnectionA" but I expect there's more. But there are hundreds and hundreds of dlls and functions to sift through.

Is there a way to get a list of the things that would come up in red?